# Android spinner - Set current value from Sqlite

Tags: android, spinner

I have a problem with a spinner in my app for android.

In one activity, I list all the values from one table, and click in one, I can edit the values of the record.
For that, I open another activity, and send the database ID.
In this new activity, I load the values acordind that ID and update the edittexts.
But, I have a problem with my spinner.
I populate that with another "table, but after this how I can "move the selected value" to the correct?
For example, I have this tables:
CUSTOMERS:
id, name, age, address, phone, idtype
TYPE:
id, name, obs

When I load the values in my activity, from the selected customer, I will get the IDTYPE of my type. But, in the spinner I only have the "name".

How can I do that???
Any ideas?

Here's the code:
    public class AlteraApiarios extends Activity {
    String Id;
    EditText etNumero,etNome,etLocal,etLatitude,etLongitude,etDataCria;
    CheckBox cbZona;
    Spinner spTipo;
    Button btGravar,btAnular;
    String [] ArrayTipo,IdBD;
    SQLiteDatabase bancoDados=null;
    Cursor cursor;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alteraapiarios);
    Inicializa_Objectos();
    Carrega_Spinner();
    Listeners();

    Intent iDadosRecebidos = getIntent();
    if (iDadosRecebidos != null )
    {
        Id=iDadosRecebidos.getStringExtra("id");
        Prepara_Alteracao();
    }
    else finish();
}

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

public void Prepara_Alteracao(){
    try{
        bancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase("GESTAPI", MODE_WORLD_READABLE , null);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Apiarios WHERE id=" +Id;
        cursor=bancoDados.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        etNumero.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Numero")));
        etNome.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Nome")));
        etLocal.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Local")));
        etDataCria.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DataCria")));
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ZControlada")).equals("1")){
            cbZona.setChecked(true);
        } else cbZona.setChecked(false);
        etLatitude.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPSLat")));
        etLongitude.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPSLon")));

----->>>>>>>>       spTipo.setSelection(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TipoApi")));



        bancoDados.close();
        }
        catch (Exception erro){
            MostraMensagem("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro ao consultar a Base de Dados: "+erro);
        }
}


public boolean Valida_Dados(){
    if (etNumero.length()<=0) return false;
    if (etNome.length()<=0) return false;
    return true;
}

public void Carrega_Spinner(){
    try{
        bancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase("GESTAPI", MODE_WORLD_READABLE , null);
        cursor=bancoDados.query("TiposApi", new String [] {"id","Tipo"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ArrayTipo=new String[cursor.getCount()];
        IdBD=new String[cursor.getCount()];
        for (int i=0; i != cursor.getCount() ; i++)
        {
            ArrayTipo[i]=""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Tipo"));
            IdBD[i]=""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    bancoDados.close();
    }
    catch (Exception erro){
        MostraMensagem("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro ao consultar a Base de Dados: "+erro);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ArrayTipo);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spTipo.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void Inicializa_Objectos(){
    etNome=(EditText) findViewById(R.idApiario.etNome);
    etNumero=(EditText) findViewById(R.idApiario.etNumero);
    etLocal=(EditText) findViewById(R.idApiario.etLocal);
    etLatitude=(EditText) findViewById(R.idApiario.etLatitude);
    etLongitude=(EditText) findViewById(R.idApiario.etLongitude);
    cbZona=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.idApiario.cbZona);
    spTipo=(Spinner) findViewById(R.idApiario.spTipo);
    etDataCria=(EditText) findViewById(R.idApiario.etDataCria);
    btGravar=(Button) findViewById(R.idApiario.btGravar);
    btAnular=(Button) findViewById(R.idApiario.btAnular);       
}

public void Listeners(){
    etDataCria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AlteraApiarios.this,MudaData.class));
        }
    });

    btAnular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Prepara_Alteracao();
        }
    });

    btGravar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}

public void MostraMensagem(String Titulo, String Mensagem)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder msg =new AlertDialog.Builder(AlteraApiarios.this);
    msg.setTitle(Titulo);
    msg.setMessage(Mensagem);
    msg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    msg.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Please proof read your questions and consider using a spell checker to help.

Comment: Please could you add your code, maybe the community help much more easier.

Comment: Done :) How can I move the spinner to my "value"?